# What is good practice for passing via modules both a class and an instance of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I import object A in my program's main `index.js` file. I create a new instance using `new A()`. Now, I want other files to be able to import the instance of the class I created in the index file. Right now I've been doing a sort of hack, where in `A.js` I do the following:

```
module.exports = {
    A: A,
    instance: null
}
```

And in `index.js`, I `require(A.js)`, then set `A.instance = new A.A`.

This is very ugly, and I don't want to create a separate file for every class I want to instantiate and pass THAT around, either.

What's a good, clean way of doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you need a singleton.

Comment: Here's a rough example https://gist.github.com/iSkore/de7b7bfa4aaa857f6664d763d1b0959c

Comment: How about exporting the instance from `index.js` and then importing that in all the files that need it?

Comment: You might as well use global variables right away.